# How to get a button to hide properly?

Tags: swift, button, hidden

In my app, you can increment through an array using the "next" button. Each time you hit next, the next item in the array is displayed in a label. I want another button to hide and unhide depending on which item is in the array/displayed in the label. I tried the code below, but the button is always showing no matter which item is displayed. How do I get the button to hide when the respective item is not showing?

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}



@IBOutlet weak var quotesLabel: UILabel!
var firstQuote = -1
var quotes = ["The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown",
                            "Everytime you spend money, you're casting a vote for the type of world you want - Anna Lappe",
                            "Buy less, choose well, make it last - Vivienne Westwood",
                            "The future depends on what we do in the present - Mahatma Gandhi",
]


@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
   
    if firstQuote < quotes.count{
    firstQuote = (firstQuote + 1) % quotes.count
    quotesLabel.text = quotes[firstQuote]
    }
    
    let quote1 = "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown"
    let quote = quotesLabel.text

        let button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Heart"), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button1)
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50)
        button1.isHidden = true
       
        if quote == quote1{
                button1.isHidden = false
            } else {
                button1.isHidden = true
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't say that I fully understand why this solution to my question worked, but by first putting the button into a view it solved my issue.

```
let view1 = UIView()
view.addSubview(view1)
view1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 200, height: 100)
view1.backgroundColor = .blue

let button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Heart"), for: .normal)
view1.addSubview(button1)
button1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
button1.isHidden = true
```